# Is it good practice to fetch current time from internet?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, time

I am making a mobile application and I need to have the current time. However, I don't want to depend on the user's phone time since it can be changed to whatever they want. Is it a good practice to fetch from a server its local time every minute or similar interval?

P.S: The app will use the time to show if a shop is open or closed so I don't mind about different timezones, I only need the time in the server's timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the need of the application. If your application would require a connection from the internet, then yes. You can also put that in case there is an issue catching the online time, you can just take the user's time.

From personal experience I never had issues that the user would want to change their phone time, but there have been a few exception.

Answer (score 0):

To use server times is fine. But based on that making decisions on data (shop open/not) is not a good practice. Whenever you make an api call, get the status if its closed or not. This will avoid user side data issues

If you want to show this information on a single shop page, fetch the time difference between current time and closing time from the server. This will help you to maintain the status on app side. this should not be for a very long time. You can use this solution if the difference is less than 10 or 15 mins.